# How to show the saved text in text field

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

In my HTML page, there is a button `new` and a button `modify`, when I click the button `new`, a new page will show with an empty single line text field, the code of the text field is:

```
<input type="text" name="functionInfo.paramsText"/>
```

so I can input some text in the text field and save it into the database (the data will be put to Java and saved into a database), this is exactly what I want, but when I click `modify` to modify a text which has been stored in the database, the new page is shown with an empty text field, how can I get a text field with the stored text shown on it? So I can see what I have saved before.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Struts tags then it's simply

```
<s:textfield name="functionInfo.paramsText"/>
```

The `value` will be set via evaluating OGNL expression in the `name` attribute. You only need to provide a bean `functionInfo` with property `paramsText` and getters for both.

If you put a bean to the action class, then using a getter it's accessible from the value stack via OGNL since the action bean is on top of the value stack.